# Capitalization of "tribe" and its derivatives in the United States

Tags: american-english, capitalization, proper-nouns, government

In these examples, when should "Tribe" or "Tribal" be capitalized?

"This rulemaking will preempt State, local, and **Tribal** requirements but does not propose any regulation that has substantial direct effects on the States, the relationship between the national government and the States, or the distribution of power and responsibilities among the various levels of government."

"The Federal hazmat law contains an express preemption provision [49 U.S.C. 5125 (b)] that preempts State, local, and **Indian Tribal** requirements on the following subjects:"

My assumption is that because they aren't proper nouns, they shouldn't be capitalized.

Comment: They are capitalized. That's the point. Basically, out of respect despite the fact that Amerindian peoples have been ruthlessly mistreated. If a law is written a particular way, that is a fact. Not something to be argued about.

Comment: Unless it's in a title or the first word in a sentence, only capitalize proper nouns. All common nouns should be in lowercase. In that passage, *state*, *local*, *tribal*, *states*, and *federal* should all be lowercase. (Only *Indian* should remain capitalized, since that is a proper noun here.) Although I note the inconsistency between the use of *tribal requirements* in the first paragraph and *Indian tribal requirements* in the second paragraph. It's possible in this case that there is a proper noun of *Indian Tribal*, but it should be used in both paragraphs if that's the case.

Comment: According to the GPO style guide state should be capitalized.

Comment: Proper adjectives are capitalised also. And GPO style guidelines in this area are as close to Style Czar diktats as it gets. I'd only go against such if I were against it on principle, and I'm all for this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears (from a comment) that you're asking about the US Government Publishing Office style guidelines.

It appears that according to the [2016 edition of the GPO Style Manual](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2016/pdf/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2016.pdf), *tribe* and *tribal* should always be capitalized when they refer to federally recognized American Indian tribes.

So it would be: "Many members of the Suquamnish *Tribe* live on the Port Madison Reservation. The *Tribal* leaders work on projects that provide cultural, educational, and recreational resources for the community. The *Tribe* has 890 enrolled members."

But: "The survivors of the shipwreck formed two *tribes*."

And: "The *tribal* delegation from Greenland arrived yesterday."

> **Names of organized bodies
> 3.18.**
>
> ...
>
> American Indian and Alaska Native federally recognized entities: 
> Shawnee  Tribe,  **the  Tribe**;  Cherokee  Nation,  the  Nation;  Alturas  Indian  Rancheria, the Rancheria; Cahuilla Band of Indians, the Band; Takotna Village, the Village; Akiak Native Community, the Community

(emphasis added)

> **4. Capitalization Examples**
>
> ...
>
> Tribe; Tribal (federally recognized)

This is somewhat counter-intuitive, both because it's different from many other guidelines and because it doesn't seem to fit a consistent pattern within the GPO guidelines.

For example, we're told to always capitalize *Navy*, but *naval* is not capitalized.  You'd think that the same rule might apply to *Tribe* and *tribal*.

Comment: The main source of the OP's being puzzled by this practice is that *tribe* is not a proper noun, so it may help to note the rule requires that the word be capitalised only when it refers to a Tribe within the United States that is explicitly recognised as a Tribe by the U.S. government. The word would not be capitalised, even within the same document, if used to refer to some tribe somewhere else in the world. This makes *Tribe* somewhat akin to proper names, unlike *tribe* which is indeed not a proper name.

Comment: @jsw29, thanks for pointing that out.  I'll amend my answer.

Comment: If I may - would the same rule apply to "Indian tribe?" With "Indian Tribe" being correct?

Comment: @BrettA, I'm not an expert, I'm just interpreting the document I linked.  But from my reading, it would be "Indian Tribe" when you're talking about a [federally recognized tribe](https://www.ncsl.org/research/state-tribal-institute/list-of-federal-and-state-recognized-tribes.aspx), and "Indian tribe" when discussing anyone else (such as a made-up tribe, a Canadian First Nation that's not also recognized by the US - e.g. not the Cree who live in both Canada and the US - indigenous peoples of Latin America, or tribes from India)