# Is "state" capitalized in lieu of the name?

Tags: word-usage, capitalization

When referring to the "politically organized body of people usually occupying a definite territory" in lieu of the proper name, should state be capitalized?

Example:

> He will liaise with State and local governmental regulatory departments.

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference but do you mean state as in sovereign nation (France, Germany), or as in subdivision of the US (Alabama, Tennessee)?

Comment: Capitalisation of *State* in this example is a an instance of a more general phenomenon; see [When do you capitalize a reference to a specific instance of a general concept?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/468985/when-do-you-capitalize-a-reference-to-a-specific-instance-of-a-general-concept)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a fairly free choice. Certainly, any prescriptive 'rule' claimed to hold here would doubtless be challenged ... a capital to signify esteem, or a lowercase letter to show non-specificity.

The [White House](https://www.whitehouse.gov/about-the-white-house/our-government/state-local-government/#:%7E:text=Whereas%20the%20Federal%20Government%20and,directly%20elected%20by%20the%20people.) chooses:

> - Powers not granted to the Federal government are reserved for States and the people, which are divided between State and local governments.

Whereas [USA.gov](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22State+and+local+government%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&biw=1314&bih=755&ei=I0TBZNaJCaeshbIP592_6Ac&ved=0ahUKEwiWp8WP4KyAAxUnVkEAHefuD30Q4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22State+and+local+government%22&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiHCJTdGF0ZSBhbmQgbG9jYWwgZ292ZXJubWVudCIyBhAAGAcYHjIGEAAYBxgeMgYQABgHGB4yBhAAGAcYHjIGEAAYBxgeMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgAQyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgARI1VZQwkVY2UxwAngBkAEAmAFWoAHpAaoBATO4AQPIAQD4AQHCAgoQABhHGNYEGLADwgIHEAAYDRiABOIDBBgAIEGIBgGQBgg&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) uses

> - Find contact information for state and local government services, your governor, and more.

And likewise [IRS](https://www.irs.gov/government-entities/federal-state-local-governments):

> - Find tax information for federal, state and local government entities

Indeed, lower-case seems by far the more common choice.

Comment: **(1)** The choice exists because *state* in the US contexts, can be thought of as either a common noun (as it generaly is), or a proper name of sorts (one of the United States). **(2)** The word is capitalised in the Constitution, and is thus often capitalised in the texts that echo the Constitution (note that the White House quotation paraphrases the Tenth Amendment). **(3)** The quotations in this answer are about states/States generally, while in the OP's example the word is used 'in lieu of the proper name' (presumably of one particular state).

Comment: Related: [Capitalization of "tribe" and its derivatives in the United States](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/534422).